# Federated Identity Management: ADFS vs OpenID

Tags: openid, adfs, federated-identity

I'm new to Federated Identity Management. I'm trying to understand the differences between the authentication protocols and concepts.

I understood the difference/relationship between OpenID and OAuth. However, I'm still confused about the differences between ADFS, OpenID, IDaaS and Claim-based authentication concept.

I'm looking for high level explanation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, let me try to explain this:

- OAuth 2 - Protocol for delegated authorization;
- OpenID Connect (OIDC) - Protocol built over OAuth2 that allows delegated authentication; Instead of my App implementing the authentication, the authentication is realized by a third party.
- Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) is not a protocol or framework. Instead, it is a software developed by Microsoft that enables single sign-on and Federation for Windows networks.
- Claim-based is the foundation of SAML and OIDC JWT tokens. These tokens have assertions about the subject (entity authenticated) and are usually signed.

Summarizing:

- OIDC and OAuth 2.0 are protocols. They don't dictate which or how your Federation will work. OAuth2 takes place at the authorization stage and OpenID Connect at the authentication and federation phases. With the public key exposed by the OpenID Connect Provider, any company can validate the ID Token and, therefore, be part of the Federation.
- ADFS is a product that allows Federation based on SAML protocol (secure but heavier than OIDC)
- Claim-based is used both in OIDC and SAML protocols. The tokens have information that the issuers claim to be correct about some entity. If you rely on a token issued by a third party, you become a relying party.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, SAML and OIDC do the same job, so, at least theoretically, it should be possible to have ADFS (which is just a product) and make it use OIDC instead of SAML?

Comment: In addition to the question above, how SSO is related to this? And is SSO supported only by Microsoft or it is a general concept?

Comment: SSO is a concept. One time authenticated in one domain, this authentication​ remains valid in others​ domains​. You can use a LDAP as user registry and its authentication generate an OIDC token. ADFS extends the LDAP for federation, but targeting Windows network, not applications. Behind ADFS there is a LDAP, that can be thought as a database optimized for read operations. I not sure if you can use ADSF as a simple LDAP. I will do some research and respond back.

Comment: ADSF is a Federated server that issues SAML assertions. There is a OAuth 2 profile to translate a SAML in a Access Token. Consequently, you can use ADSF to do the authentication of the resource owner, before the recording​ of the OIDC or OAuth permission. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7522 and keep in touch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I have better understanding of the topic. Please feel free to add any comments in the future if you come up with something new.

Answer (score 7):

Just to expand.

When you said, OpenID did you mean that or did you mean OpenID Connect? They are two different protocols and OpenID is very rarely used these days.

ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) is the only ADFS that has full OpenID Connect / OAuth support (i.e. all four profiles).

Only ADFS 4.0 can use LDAP v3.0 and above for authentication. On earlier versions you have to use AD.

Also SAML and WS-Fed normally use SAML tokens not JWT ones.

Just to point out, ADFS also supports WS-Federation.

Comment: Thanks to pointing out to ADFS 4.0 OpenId connect support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs